# Marionette + RequireJS: Doing a require inside ItemView.render()

Tags: requirejs, marionette

I'm trying to load and render additional views async and append them to the ItemView.

Simplified code - why is `$el` not defined in the `require()` block in `render()` - what am I missing here?  Am I not using RequireJS properly, or Marionette, or just my inexperience with javascript?

What is the recommended way of doing this?  It needs to be dynamic as additional section views could be available at runtime that I don't know about yet as registered by plugins.

```
define(['require','marionette', 'App', 'swig', 'backbone.wreqr','text!./settings.html'],
function (require,Marionette, App,Swig, Wreqr,  settingsHtml )
{

    var sectionViews = ['./settingscontent/GeneralView'];

    var SettingsView = Marionette.ItemView.extend(
        {
            template: Swig.compile(settingsHtml),
            commands: new Wreqr.Commands(),
            initialize: function ()
            {
                this.commands.addHandler('save', function (options, callback)
                {
                    callback();
                });
                Marionette.ItemView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
            },
            render: function()
            {

                Marionette.ItemView.prototype.render.call(this);
                var $el = this.$el;
                var self = this;
                require(sectionViews, function (View)
                {
                    $el.find('div.tab-content').append(new View(self.model).render().$el);
                // $el is not defined 
                // self != outer this - $el is an empty div 
                });
                return this;

            }
        }
     return SettingsView;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to overload itemview.render?

Why not use the built in onrender event 
https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.itemview.md#render--onrender-event

from that documentation :

```
Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  onRender: function(){
   // manipulate the `el` here. it's already
   // been rendered, and is full of the view's
   // HTML, ready to go.
 }
});
```

seems easier and more typical of marionette usage

Comment: I'd downvote you if I had enough points, your answer doesn't address the main point of my query re the require().  The result is the same in onRender (already tested)

Comment: When I see code that is ignoring the patterns I always address that first, it's generally an indication the programmer is trying to make a cat bark.  In your case you should still look at why you are doing that.  but, you are also incorrectly scoped. the  require(sectionViews, function (View)  creates a new scope for you so the $el is not accessible.  search google for javascript scoping .

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `this` inside the function to the `SettingsView` object. Something like:

```js
render: function()
{
     Marionette.ItemView.prototype.render.call(this);
     var $el = this.$el;
     var self = this;
     require(sectionViews, _.bind(function (View)
     {
         ...
     }, this));
     return this;
 }
```

The local variables will not be visible inside the bound function. You can use `this` and `this.$el` safely however.